# Plot communities with igraph

Tags: r, plot, igraph, modularity

I want to create a graph plot with each community of nodes been covered by some background color, similar to the graph by the following code

```
karate <- graph.famous("Zachary")
wc <- walktrap.community(karate)
modularity(wc)
membership(wc)
plot(wc, karate)
```

But different from this approach, I want to: (1) group the nodes by myself, instead of resulting from community detection algorithm. I achieved this by `wc$membership <- some_vector`; (2) plot such graph possibly with overlap between communities, then how can I assign one node to multiple communities?

Answer (score 3):

Plot the graph itself instead of the community structure, and use an appropriately constructed `mark.groups` argument to `plot()` to tell igraph which groups should be enclosed by the same group. The following quote is from the manual page of `plot.igraph`:

> **mark.groups**: A list of vertex id vectors. It is interpreted as a set of vertex groups. Each vertex group is highlighted, by plotting a colored smoothed polygon around and "under" it.