# visualize overlapping communities in graph by any of the python or R modules

Tags: python, r, networkx, visualization, igraph

How can I visualize communities if there are overlapping communities in the graph?
I can use any module in python (networkx, igraph, matplotlib, etc.) or R.

For example, information on nodes, edges, and the nodes in each community is given as follows. Note that node G spans two communities.

```
list_nodes = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E','F','G','H','I','J']
tuple_edges = [('A','B'),('A','C'),('A','D'),('B','C'),('B','D'), ('C','D'),('C','E'),
              ('E','F'),('E','G'),('F','G'),('G','H'),
              ('G','I'), ('G','J'),('H','I'),('H','J'),('I','J'),]
list_communities = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],['E','F','G'],['G', 'H','I','J']]
```

I would like a plot that visualizes the community as shown below.

[image]

In networkx, it is possible to colour-code each node like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43541376/how-to-draw-communities-with-networkx), but this method is not suitable when communities overlap.

In igraph, communities can be visualised using the community extraction method included in the package, as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51102350/python-remove-overlapping-communities-in-igraph-plot). However, in my case I want to define communities using the list of nodes contained in each community.

Comment: Question is similar to `Plot communities with igraph`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913419/plot-communities-with-igraph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is an option for `igraph` within `R`.

---

I think you may have to annotate the community info manually (see `grp` below) and then use it when plotting, e.g.,

```
g <- graph_from_data_frame(df, directed = FALSE)
grp <- lapply(
  groups(cluster_edge_betweenness(g)),
  function(x) {
    c(
      x,
      names(which(colSums(distances(g, x) == 1) > 1))
    )
  }
)
plot(g, mark.groups = grp)
```

or using `max_cliques` with minimal size `3` (thank @clp's comment)

```
g <- graph_from_data_frame(df, directed = FALSE)
grp <- max_cliques(g, min = 3)
plot(g, mark.groups = grp)
```

[image]

## Data

```
df <- data.frame(
  from = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "E", "E", "F", "G", "G", "G", "H", "H", "I"),
  to = c("B", "C", "D", "C", "D", "D", "E", "F", "G", "G", "H", "I", "J", "I", "J", "J")
)
```

Comment: The community structure in this question can also be re-engineered by `grp <- max_cliques(g, min=3)`.

Comment: @clp Yes, exactly, that simplifies a lot! Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding, new to graph networks, any good tutorials or book I can use to learn quickly and use same on a project?

Comment: @wwnde Perhaps starting from any textbook of graph theory